# Is there a more functional way to do this sequence of requests?

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

There is a REST api which returns a json with a list of jsons (named results) and a url to the next batch of results (this url is equal to null for the last "page"). I want to make an aggregate of the whole results (concatenate all the lists of jsons into a single one). I am using spray-client to do the GET requests and this is what I came up with:

```
  val request: HttpRequest => Future[MyResponse] = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[MyResponse]
  def getCandidatesStartingFrom(url: String): Future[List[Candidate]] =
      request(Get(url)).flatMap {
        response =>
            val next = response.next match {
              case Some(nextUrl) => getCandidatesStartingFrom(nextUrl)
              case None => Future.successful(Nil)
            }
            next.map(response.results ++ _)
      }
```

My question is: is there a way to make this more functional? (avoid the recursion or maybe make it tail recursive?). Or even, does spray support idiomatically this kind of aggregations?

Comment: This looks completely function to me. I don't see any mutable state.

Comment: @ziggystar Not completely functional to me. Its not tail recursive for one thing. But what bothers me the most is the pattern matching for the `response.next` option: it looks like a map (which would allow me to put the whole code in for comprehension) but in the None case there is this trivial `Future.succesful(Nil)`. Isn't there a way to take advantage of what Option offers?

Answer (score 0):

```
request(Get(url)).flatMap {
        response =>
            val next = response.next match {
              case Some(nextUrl) => getCandidatesStartingFrom(nextUrl)
              case None => Future.successful(Nil)
            }
            next.map(response.results ++ _)
      }
```

can be written as the following. But it's not that much of an improvement.

```
for{   
  response <- request(Get(url))   
  nextUrl <- response.next
               .map(getCandidatesStartingFrom)
               .getOrElse(Future.successful(Nil)) 
} yield response.results ++ nextUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently recursive. Your "recursive" call to `getCandidatesStartingFrom` is not actually in the call-stack of the parent call to `getCandidatesStartingFrom`, but rather in the anonymous lambda passed to `flatMap`.

That is, `getCandidatesStartingFrom`:

1. asks spray to begin an HTTP request (which immediately returns a future)
2. calls `flatMap` on that future with *an anonymous function* to run when it completes. this, too, immediately returns a future.
3. returns that future to the caller